# Unable to shutdown workstation

Tags: linux, centos, shutdown

I've an issue with a workstation running CentOS 7.4. I'm unable to shut it down. 
Whatever the methode (GUI, command `poweroff`, `/sbin/shutdown now`) I use, it automatically reboots.

I don't find anything in the log either.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `shutdown -r` means _reboot after shutdown_

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant it without the `-r`. Corrected.